# Exctract authorization name of express route using bash script

Tags: bash, azure, command-line-interface, express-router

I am trying to fetch the name of express route and its respective authorization names in a list using bash script. But i end up with no values. Please let me know what is the syntax issue here

```
rgList=$(az group list --subscription "sub1" --query [].name |  cut -f2)
erList=$(az network express-route list --subscription "sub1" --query [].name)
for i in "{$rgList[@]}"; do
    for j in "{$erList[@]}"; do
    hubname+=$(az network express-route auth list --circuit-name $j --resource-group $i --query [].authorizations[].name)
    done
done
echo "{$hubname[@]}"
```

The array $hubname[@] returns nothing
I need the hubname to be a key value pair like hubname=[{ercircuitname1,auth1},{ercircuitname2,auth2}]

Comment: cut-n-paste your code (along with appropriate shebang) into [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net), make the suggested changes and if you're still having problems then come back and update the question with: complete output from `typeset -p rgList erList`, your updated code, the (wrong) output generated by your code and the (correct) expected output; generally speaking your variable references have misplaced braces, eg: `{$hubname[@]}` should be `${hubname[@]}`

Comment: Thanks I was able to resolve the errors